Im confused on how conservation of momentum works mathematically for a problem involving a skater throwing two weights from rest
Here's the question.

A 40-kg skateboarder on a 3-kg board is training with two 5-kg weights. Beginning from rest, she throws the weights horizontally, one at a time from her board. The speed of each weight is 7 m/s relative to her and the board after it is thrown. Assume the board rolls without friction. (a) How fast is she propelled in the opposite direction after throwing the first weight? (b) the second weight?

The initial question makes complete sense as it's just a basic application of the law of conservation of momentum.
$M$ = Girl + skateboard
$m$ = 5kg weight
$V_{sg1}$ = Velocity of the skater relative to the ground
$v_{wg}$ = velocity of the weight relative to the ground
$v_{ws1}$ = velocity of the weight relative to the skater
Heres my math so far, please point out anything thats wrong with it. The subscript 0 represents the momentum before the weight is thrown, 1 represents after it is thrown for the first time.
$P_{sys0} = P_{sys1}$
$P_{sys0} = 0$
$P_{sys1} = (M + m)V_{sg1} + mv_{wg1}$
$(M + m)V_{sg1} + mv_{wg1} = 0$
$v_{wg1} = v_{ws1} + V_{sg1}$
With all of this you can find the speed of the girl after the first throw as:
$V_{sg1} = -\frac{m}{M+2m}v_{ws1}$
The problem is when i'm trying to find the second velocity after the second throw. No matter what I tried I couldn't figure out the correct answer so I gave up and looked at the book. It unfortunately just confused me more. The book says this:
$P_{sys2} = P_{sys1}$
so far so good, but here's where I'm confused. Why is this true?
$MV_{sg2} + mv_{wg2} = (M + m)V_{sg1}$
When
$P_{sys1} = (M + m)V_{sg1} + mv_{wg1}$
What happened to the $mv_{wg1}$?
The first thing I thought was that maybe $mv_{wg1}$ was maybe actually $P_{sys0}$ but that wouldn't make since because the signs would be different. I'm currently just learning about momentum straight from a textbook, so I may have misunderstood one of the prior theorems.

The equation as written implies that after we throw the first weight away, we can ignore it as not part of the system anymore. We can model the second step of the system as just the skater and the one weight they're holding. The momentum of the first weight is constant after we throw it away, so it won't affect the momentum balance in subsequent steps.
You aren't wrong, though, we could include the $mv_{wg1}$ term on the right side of the equation in the $P_{sys1}$ term, but then we'd also have to include it on the left in the $P_{sys2}$ term. If we model the system as the skater plus both weights at each time step, we need to include it in the total momentum at each time stem. You can see that if we do include it on both sides of the equation, it can be subtracted from both sides again, leaving you with the equation from the book.

Thank you! That makes sense now, I wish the book would have mentioned that in some way within the questions answer.
